# Parameters will not be used with Invoke-Command remotely, -computername comes back null

Tags: host, invoke-command

I would like to know how to pass parameters with the Invoke-Command to be used within a script to run remotely.

```
enter code here
Param(
[string]$cname = (Read-Host "Computer Name?") ,
[string]$event = (Read-Host "What event?") ,
[string]$eventfilter = (Read-Host "What key word are you looking for?") '
[string]$amount = (Read-Host "How many events do you want to see?")
)
Invoke-Command -cn $cname -ScriptBlock {Get-EventLog -cn $cname -LogName $event -Message "*$eventfilter*" -Newest $amount | FT -Wrap}
```

I would like to know if this is possible and what I would need to do to fix this script?
Thanks

Comment: Doing some research it seems that I need to use Parameters to pass the variables through the Invoke-Command cmdlet. Still trying to figure that part out.

Comment: Param(
  [string]$cname = 'Read-Host Computer Name?',
  [string]$event = 'Read-Host What event?',
  [string]$eventfilter = 'Read-Host What key word are you looking for?',
  [string]$amount = 'Read-Host How many events do you want to see?'
  )     Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-EventLog -cn $cname -LogName $event -Message "*$eventfilter*" | FT -Wrap}

Answer (score 0):

```
$cname = Read-Host "Computer Name?"
$event = Read-Host "What event?"
$eventfilter = Read-Host "What key word are you looking for?"
$amount = Read-Host "How many events do you want to see?"


Invoke-Command -cn $cname -ScriptBlock {Get-EventLog -cn $using:cname -LogName $using:event -Message "*$eventfilter*" -Newest $using:amount | FT -Wrap}
```

Comment: A Using variable can be used only with Invoke-Command, Start-Job, or InlineScript in the script workflow. When it is used with Invoke-Command, 
the Using variable is valid only if the script block is invoked on a remote computer.